# Restarting and Android service following app upgrade

Tags: android, android-intent, package, upgrade, broadcast

I have a service that is kept running via a "Watchdog" alarmmanager which checks if the service is running and re-starts it if required.

This works fine until the user updates the app from the app store. Presumably the process of deleting the app from the phone and replacing the package invalidates my AlarmMgr entries.

Can someone tell me what intents I should use to re-schedule the service based on package changes which occur as a result of an app being upgraded from the app store.

One or more of the following would seem to be required.

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_CHANGED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_INSTALL"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

[HERE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED) they say, that *"the newly installed package does not receive this broadcast"*. I think It will be the same for all of these broadcasts and It's for security reasons. Also `PACKAGE_INSTALL` is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Came across this question on Google, so thought it would be worth updating the state of the answer. Since Honeycomb, there is now ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED which is sent to your application when it is updated, which is designed for this kind of use case.

Unlike in 2012 when this question was asked, support for Android 2.3 or below is no longer important.